# Matplotlib: Legend for different coloured dot and line

Tags: matplotlib

See the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

graph_data = [5, 8, 7, 9]
x = range(len(graph_data))
y = graph_data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Comment the following two lines
plt.plot(x, y, markersize=6, color='g', label='blah 1')
plt.plot(x, y, 'ob', markersize=6, label='blah 2')

# ...and uncomment the following line
#plt.plot(x, y, '-ob', markersize=6, label='blah')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
filename = 'test2.pdf'
fig.savefig(filename, bbox_inches='tight')
```

What I ty to achieve is different colors for the dots (`o`) and the line segments joining them (`-`) by doing both separately. I am able to get it:

[image]

However, the problem aries when I try to assign label to it (in legend). I get the legend in this form:
[image]

... whereas I want in this form:

[image]

The later legend can be obtained by commenting the two `plot` lines and uncommenting the `plot` line below. However, this loses the colour variation I am looking for. How can I fix this (get the correct colour varition as well as a proper legend)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite straightforward by changing the marker face color and edge color. Here `color='green'` will first apply to both marker and line. Then you can change the marker edge color (`mec`) and marker face color (`mfc`) to blue

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(x, y, '-o', color='green', mfc='b', 
         mec='b', markersize=6, label='blah')

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]